# Show that Vandermonde matrix $_$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x_1 < x_2 < . . . < x_m$, and let $y_1 , y_2 , . . . , y_m$ be real numbers. There exists exactly one polynomial $p$ of degree $≤ m − 1,$ such that $p(x_i) = y_i, 1 ≤ i ≤ m.$ This is equivalent to showing that the Vandermonde matrix $V_m$ is invertible. Prove it using the following steps.

> 1. Explain: It suffices to prove that $p(x) = 0$ is the only solution when all the $y_i$ are zero.
> 2. Assume that $p$ were a polynomial of degree $≤ m − 1$ with $p(x_i ) = 0$ for
>      all $i$. Show that there are $m − 1$ different points in which the
>      derivative $p'$ is zero.

**My attempt:** 
1. $$p(x)=\sum_{j=1}^mc_jx^{j-1}=V_m\vec{c}=\vec{y}.$$ This is a system of linear questions. So, $V_m$ is invertible if columns  are linearly independent. In other words the only solution to $V_m\vec{c}=\vec{0}$ is $\vec{c}=\vec{0}.$ 
I'm stuck on the second point, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Rolle's theorem.: If $p$ is differentiable and If $p(x_i)=p(x_{i+1})=0$ (and $x_i<x_{i+1}$) there is some $\xi\in(x_i,x_{i+1})$ such that $p'(\xi)=0$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Pleaes your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following a request I transform my comment above into an answer:

*Rolle's theorem*: If $p$ is differentiable and if $p(x_i)=p(x_{i+1})=0 $
(and $x_i<x_{i+1}$) there is some $ξ∈(x_i,x_{i+1}$) such that $p′(ξ)=0$.

Comment: So, the polynomial of the degree $m-1$ has at most $m-1$ roots, therefore, shouldn't it have $m-2$ different points where the derivative is 0 (since between any  two zeros of the function there is one point where the derivative is 0)?

Comment: We want to show with induction that $p$ as above is$\equiv 0$. The induction hypothesis and Rolle show that $p'\equiv 0$. Thus $p$ is constant and therefore $\equiv 0$  since $p$ by assumption has the zeroes $x_i$.

Comment: Can you clarify it a little bit more? So from what I get, we want to prove with induction that polynomial $p(x)=0$. So base case is trivial $(n=0):$ 0=0. Now we make the induction hypothesis that polynomial of degree $m-1 \ \ p(x_i)=0$ for all $i$.We want to show that polynomial of degree $m \ \ p(x_i)=0$ for all $i$. By Rolle's theorem there exist $m-1$ different points where $p'=0$. How do we know that $p'$ is 0 everywhere (so that p is constant)? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @dxdydz: $p'$ has degree $m-2$ and vanishes at $m-2$ points  $\xi_i\in(x_i,x_{i+1})$. Thus by induction hypothesis $p'$ has to vanish everywhere.